# Handling postbacks from an AJAX Rating Control inside a Repeater

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, ajaxcontroltoolkit, repeater, rating

I have a Repeater control with a Rating control (from the latest AJAX Control Toolkit) inside:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repStudents" runat="server" onitemcommand="repStudents_ItemCommand">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
    <asp:Rating ID="warnings" runat="server" Direction="NotSet" MaxRating="3" StarCssClass="star" EmptyStarCssClass="em" FilledStarCssClass="gr" WaitingStarCssClass="gr" AutoPostBack="True" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="warn"></asp:Rating>
    <br />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the code behind, I have:

```
protected void repStudents_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
  //Custom log function
  Log.Append(e.CommandName + " " + e.CommandArgument);
}
```

All renders fine. However, when I click on a rating the page posts back but `repStudents_ItemCommand` is not fired. How can I fix this?

Note that if I put a Button in the same Repeater, `repStudents_ItemCommand` fires correctly when I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rating control does not support CommandName/CommandArgument properties. But you can extend it as follows:

```
public class ExRating : Rating {

    [Category("Behavior")]
    public string CommandName {
        get { return (string)ViewState["CommandName"] ?? string.Empty; }
        set { ViewState["CommandName"] = value; }
    }

    [Category("Behavior")]
    public string CommandArgument {
        get { return (string)ViewState["CommandArgument"] ?? string.Empty; }
        set { ViewState["CommandArgument"] = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnChanged(RatingEventArgs e) {
        base.OnChanged(e);
        RaiseBubbleEvent(this, new CommandEventArgs(CommandName, CommandArgument));
    }

}
```

Then replace the old control with new one:

```
<pages>
  <tagMapping>
    <add tagType="AjaxControlToolkit.Rating, AjaxControlToolkit" mappedTagType="Sample.ExRating, Sample"/>
  </tagMapping>
</pages>
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't express enough how helpful your answer has been, with the complete source code. Very kind of you.